# eIDAS - list of certified qualified electronic signature creation devices

Tags: digital-signature, eidas

In eIDAS there is written in Article 31:

> 2. On the basis of the information received, the Commission shall establish, publish and maintain a list of certified qualified electronic signature creation devices

Where can I find the list mentioned above?

Comment: IIRC you only get a list of the national list providers from the commission. Each country maintains its own (public) list then.

Comment: Something like [this list of lists](https://ec.europa.eu/information_society/policy/esignature/trusted-list/tl-mp.xml)?

Comment: I am looking for certified devices for signature creation, not list of trusted certificates.

Comment: The list of QSCDs is in the works but not ready yet, at the moment you still have to look up info at national levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list is now published [here](https://ec.europa.eu/futurium/en/content/compilation-member-states-notification-sscds-and-qscds).